# Have multiple repositories for the same class in spring data mongodb

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-data

So I have a data class x that I want to have 2 repositories for. Both repos Y and Z should be capable of storing Documents of type X.

The problem is that when I use MongoRepository in both repos .. it assumes that the collection name is X. So I was hoping there is one way to rename the collection for the Repository ... or a better approach to what I want to do here

Answer (score 0):

Try to use inheritance and define appropriate collection names in such way. May give you possibility to save in different collections but you will be still not able to specify dynamically collection names and resp. their amount at runtime.